# PostAsync HttpRequestException: Cannot decode raw data

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I'm trying to make a function to upload a file (pdf, docx, xls) to an http API. I've tried with Postman and it worked fine. But when I try from the application, is not working.

```
        private async Task UploadFile()
        {
            String fileguid = this.noteModel.Fileguid.ToString();
            try
            {
                var file = await CrossFilePicker.Current.PickFile();
                if (file == null)
                    return;

                string fileName = file.FileName;

                string url = App.apiServer + "web/Token13/" + App.token + "/" + fileguid;

                var content = new MultipartFormDataContent();
                content.Headers.ContentType.MediaType = "multipart/form-data";
                
                content.Add(new StreamContent(file.GetStream()), "file", fileName);
                var httpClient = new HttpClient();
                var response = await httpClient.PostAsync(url, content);

                String status =  response.StatusCode.ToString();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                System.Console.WriteLine("Exception choosing file: " + ex.ToString());
            }
        }
```

I have the following error at line `'var response = await httpClient.PostAsync(url, content);'`:

```
2021-02-12 20:03:58.805 Project.iOS[2202:520692] Exception choosing file: System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: cannot decode raw data ---> 
Foundation.NSErrorException: Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1015 "cannot decode raw data" 
UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=cannot decode raw data, 
NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=http://ip/appservertest/web/Token13/id, 
NSErrorFailingURLKey=http://ip/appservertest/web/Token13/id, 
_NSURLErrorRelatedURLSessionTaskErrorKey=(
    "LocalDataTask <FD8D1034-CF42-41C8-A214-BE4D87D1D15D>.<1>"
), _NSURLErrorFailingURLSessionTaskErrorKey=LocalDataTask <FD8D1034-CF42-41C8-A214-BE4D87D1D15D>.<1>, NSUnderlyingError=0x282880000 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1015 "(null)" UserInfo={NSErrorPeerAddressKey=<CFData 0x2805e64e0 [0x1f6084660]>{length = 16, capacity = 16, bytes = 0x100200505991f6e00
000000000000000}}}}
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at System.Net.Http.NSUrlSessionHandler.SendAsync (System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage request, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x001d4] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/14.2.0.12/src/Xamarin.iOS/Foundation/NSUrlSessionHandler.cs:527 
  at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.FinishSendAsyncBuffered (System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[TResult] sendTask, System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage request, System.Threading.CancellationTokenSource cts, System.Boolean disposeCts) [0x0017e] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/Current/src/Xamarin.iOS/external/corefx/src/System.Net.Http/src/System/Net/Http/HttpClient.cs:506 
  at Project.Views.NotesEdit.UploadFile () [0x0018f] in C:\Repository\Project\Project\Views\NotesEdit.xaml.cs:268
```

Could you please give me a hint, why is not working?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you have not completed your header with the `MediaTypeHeaderValue`. This works for me:

```
var content = new StreamContent(stream);
content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("form-data")
{
  FileName = imageName,
  Name = imageName
};
content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("image/jpeg");

var multipartContent = new MultipartFormDataContent();
multipartContent.Add(content);
var result = await client.PostAsync(url, multipartContent.Add);
```

Comment: Hi @Saamer, thank you for you response. I see that in your example is for image/jpeg... if I'm using docs like pdf, docx, excel files? Will work?

Comment: I've tried with a .jpg and I have the same error.

Comment: Can u create a reproducible sample and place it on Github, so I can download it and test it? @ClaudiuL93